# Match comments and multiline comments regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, match

I've this text and I need a regex pattern that matches all comments (multi-line and non):

```
# English language file
# all entries must contain a string number, followed by a space, followed by a string, ended by a pound character
# lines beginning with pound character are a comment
# blank lines are ignored

1 null#

# generic names
1900 text1234#
1901 text1234#
1902 text1234#
```

---

I thought about this:

```regex
(?:^#\s?([^\n]+))(?:\n#\s?([^\n]+))*
```

But it does not group the multi-lines comment correctly: https://regex101.com/r/LC1f5c/1

---

If, on the other hand, I repeat the second group 3 times:

```regex
(?:^#\s?([^\n]+))(?:\n#\s?([^\n]+))(?:\n#\s?([^\n]+))(?:\n#\s?([^\n]+))
```

Works the way I want (with multi-line comments only): https://regex101.com/r/FMSP13/1

Comment: Please explain in words what you mean by "works badly" and what the difference is between the results obtained by the two regexes.

Comment: @martineau I added the regex101 examples for this, as you see the second gets all groups of sentences correctly, the first doesn't.

Comment: Yes, I saw the pictures and things were not clear to me — and I didn't want to guess at what you were talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do so:

```
import re

comments = []
for comment in re.findall(r"(?:^# .*?\n)+", data, flags=re.MULTILINE):
    comments.append(comment[2:-1].split("\n# "))
```

The same using a list comprehension:

```
comments = [comment[2:-1].split("\n# ") for comment in re.findall(r"(?:^# .*?\n)+", data, flags=re.MULTILINE)]
```

**Output:**

```
[
    [
        'English language file',
        'all entries must contain a string number, followed by a space, followed by a string, ended by a pound character',
        'lines beginning with pound character are a comment', 
        'blank lines are ignored'
    ],
    [
        'generic names'
    ]
]
```

---

- `comment[2:-1]` allows not to keep the first two characters (`#` ), as well as the last character (`\n`).

---

```
(?:^# .*?\n)+
```

- `(?:)+`: Non capturing group, between one and unlimited times, as much as possible.

  - `^`: Start of the line.
  - `#` : Matches `#` .
  - `.*?`: Matches any character, between zero and unlimited times, as few as possible.
  - `\n`: Matches a newline.